# В один файл приходят и GET и POST

Tags: php, post, get

Как на php грамотно сделать чтобы в одном фале было следующее:
если нет ни POST ни GET выводим форму.
если GET ищем в БД по ид записи.
если POST добавляем данные в БД.
Уже всю голову сломал

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //Добавляем (_POST)
} elseif(!empty($_GET)) {
    // Поиск (_GET)
} else {
    // Выводим форму
}
```